# Css background-blend-mode alternative

Tags: javascript, css, cross-browser, frontend, blending

The new background-blend-mode property is really cool but it has limited support so far.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-backgroundblendmode

Has anyone used an alternative where you can blend the background color with a dom element/svg.

Answer (score 1):

That would be the [Mix Blend Mode](http://www.w3.org/TR/compositing-1/#mix-blend-mode).

Support is similar to Background Blend Mode: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mixblendmode - the `background-blend-mode` stuff seems to have landed first, but mix is not far behind.